# RegexOptions.CultureInvariant not finding matches for accents

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to create a regex that ignores accent.

For instance:

```
string s = "I am an old élephant";
string pattern = "elephant";
bool result = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.CultureInvariant).IsMatch(s);
```

My culture when I test is:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = Fr-fr
```

So I would have expected this code to find a match but it does not.

Is there an easy way to get a match for this?

I am trying to make a StringReplace overload method that would replace élèphânt with elephant and so on.

Comment: "My culture when I test is" irrelevant, since you specified `RegexOptions.CultureInvariant`.

Comment: @A.D. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following method:

```
    public string removeDiacritics(string str)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (char c in str.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD))
        {
            if (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
            {
                sb.Append(c);
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString().Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
    }
```

Then it works

```
        string s = "I am an old élephant";
        string pattern = "elephant";
        bool result = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).IsMatch(removeDiacritics(s)); //true
```

If you have to replace something e.g. iterate (backward) through the matchcollection and edit you original string depending on the indexes of each match.

Explaination: (i'm using the "I am an old élephant" string)

Let's write all chars of the original string into an list :

```
foreach (char c in str)
{
    chars1.Add(c);
}
```

[image]

As you can see the char is defined as unicode char 233 or 00E9 (see http://unicode-table.com/de/#00E9)

The normalisation is explained here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.normalizationform(v=vs.110).aspx

As the documention says:
Form D:

```
Indicates that a Unicode string is normalized using full canonical decomposition.
```

That means that the char é is "split up" into an e and an accent char.

To check that, let's output the chars of the normalised string:

```
List<char> chars2 = new List<char>();
foreach(char c in str.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD))
{
    chars2.Add(c);
}
```

[image]

As seen in the watch, the é is now normalised into 2 characters (101 (\u0065) + 769 (\u0301))

Now we have to eliminate these accents:
Iterate through all chars of the normalised string and if it's a "NonSpacingMark", add it to the StringBuilder.

MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.unicodecategory(v=vs.110).aspx

NonSpacingMark

> Nonspacing character that indicates modifications of a base character.
>   Signified by the Unicode designation "Mn" (mark, nonspacing). The
>   value is 5.

Finally to ensure that all other characters, that are now defined as 2 or 3 characters in our string, are getting "converted" into the unicode character symbol, we have to normalise our new string back to the FormC.

MSDN:
FormC:

> Indicates that a Unicode string is normalized using full canonical
>   decomposition, followed by the replacement of sequences with their
>   primary composites, if possible.

Comment: That will work. Thx for this :)

Comment: @user1519979: Maybe you should elaborate a bit how it works. I understand what you're doing, but I'm not sure everyone does...

Comment: @Sefe done.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying a Culture*In*variant regex. That means your culture is *ignored*. So you either have to remove the option...

```
bool result = new Regex(pattern).IsMatch(s);
```

...or if you want to be culture independent, expand your pattern:

```
string pattern = "[eé]lephant";
```

Comment: Default, without  RegexOptions.CultureInvariant, it does not work.
My understanding was that the  RegexOptions.CultureInvariant tag would make it match but I misunderstood.

Comment: string pattern = "[eé]lephant"; is not what I am looking for as I am looking for a generic method to find matches when comparing a string with accent to a string without accents.

I am actually trying to make a StringReplace overload method that would replace élèphânt with elephant and so on.

Comment: If you want to do that, use `String.Equals`. You can specify your culture there. Regex will help you with exact matches; for culture-sensitive searches it's not very useful. You should also update your question to provide that kind of information, otherwise you'll not get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Regular Expression, you can employ `\P{L}` to state that a given unicode chracter is a letter.

```
        string s = "I am an old ùûüÿàâçéèêëïîô";
        string pattern = @"(\p{L})";
        var regex = new Regex(pattern);
        var result = regex.Replace(s, @"$1");
        Console.WriteLine(result);//I am an old uuuyaaceeeeiio
```